# What are the main advantages / disadvantages between proposed RandomX to ProgPoW?

Tags: mining, cryptonight, mining-hardware, asic-mining, asic-development

Ethereum developers recently decided to fork off Ethash ASICs like Monero did before. However, Monero changes its CryptoNight mining algorithm only slightly every six months until a more robust alternative is ready, mainly RandomX is being discussed from what I observed.

Ethereum wants to switch to [ProgPOW](https://github.com/ifdefelse/ProgPOW) which is claimed to be hardly ASIC-able. What are the main differences between ProgPOW and RandomX and can some parts of it also benefit Monero's development in a longer-term ASIC resistant mining algorithm?

Comment: RandomJS was abandoned months ago. Current work is on RandomX.

Comment: @hyc Thanks for pointing out, missed that somehow. Will change the question to RandomX.

Answer (score 3):

> What are the main differences between ProgPOW and RandomX?

The design goal of **ProgPoW** is to have the algorithm’s requirements match what is available on commodity GPUs, while **RandomX** is inefficient (as stated on https://github.com/tevador/RandomX) on GPUs.

> can some parts of it also benefit Monero's development in a longer-term ASIC resistant mining algorithm?

Monero's developers are constantly following the evolution of the other opensource mining algorithms (as for example https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/3545) and if something can help the mining algorithm of **Monero**, it will be implemented in a safe and secure way.